# Anyway to protect JSON webservice on 2 domains that are using SSO?

Tags: json, jsonp, single-sign-on

If we're SSOing into a site on a complete different domain, is there any sort of info we can use to secure JSON webservices between the 2 domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I double posted apologies heres the answer to the related question [Recommended way for access webservices on domain A from domain B if A is SSO'ing into B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257088/recommended-way-for-access-webservices-on-domain-a-from-domain-b-if-a-is-ssoing/10430214#10430214)