# Recommended way for access webservices on domain A from domain B if A is SSO'ing into B?

Tags: web-services, single-sign-on

frontend dev here with no experience with SSO so bear with me. Keen for a high-level recommendation on the following as I can appreciate it may vary.

We've got a client setting up SSO to login to our site, and Im trying to understanding how I can safely call their webservices for user info from our domain via AJAX. Looking at their services they're asking for a User ID and Password which I dont think is usable/feasible as I assume our system would need to expose the password to the frontend which doesnt seem secure... They mentioned they could pass these via http but that doesnt seem secure either!

Is there some sort of way we can validate the webservice all via SSO or is there some other way?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the simple solution is to get the client to change the web service to use an encrypted version of the user password so they can pass that safely via http, and I turn store that in a session cookie when they first land our site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further my comment, we're pushing ahead with using the shared encryption method used for our SSO (TripleDES in ECB mode) to encrypt the token in the webservice request